# How many subgraphs of this simple graph?

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

How can I go about finding the amount of subgraphs easily?
I tried doing this:
Remove only vertices in $\binom{4}1 + \binom{4}2 + \binom{4}3 + \binom{4}4 = 20$ ways.
Remove only edges in $\binom{3}{1} +\binom{3}2 + \binom{3}3 = 7$ ways.
Remove nothing in $1$ ways.
So total is $28$.
However, the answer says that it is $35$. How did they get this?

Comment: This is a side note to the meat of the question, but $\binom41 + \binom42 + \binom43 + \binom44 = 15$, not $20$. In general, $\binom n0 + \binom n1 + \binom n2 + \dots + \binom nn = 2^n$, so $\binom n1 + \binom n2 + \dots + \binom nn = 2^n-1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you *can't* remove vertices without removing edges. What does having edge $ab$ in the subgraph mean if you don't have vertex $a$?

In fact, if we get rid of vertex $a$, we have to get rid of *all* the edges. That leaves $2^3 = 8$ subgraphs, depending on which subset of the vertices $\{b,c,d\}$ are included.

If we *do* keep $a$, then for each vertex $x \in \{b,c,d\}$ we can do one of three things:

- Keep both vertex $x$ and edge $ax$.
- Keep vertex $x$, but remove edge $ax$.
- Remove both vertex $x$ and edge $ax$.

This gives us $3^3 = 27$ subgraphs.

With $27$ subgraphs containing $a$ and $8$ subgraphs not containing $a$, we have $8+27 = 35$ subgraphs total.

Comment: If we remove vertex $a$, we are left with $8$ subgraphs because each vertex is either "remove" or "don't remove" right?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it. We have three independent choices, each one goes two ways, so there are $2^3 = 8$ outcomes.